# How & where does selenium convert java/other HL programming language commands to native javascript to interact with browser?

Tags: java, javascript, browser, selenium, webdriver

Javascript is required to interact browser elements. But selenium is providing API for all high level programming languages like Java, C# etc. Does selenium compiles these java commands to javascript code? ie how does selenium interacts with browser when the code is not been written in javascript

Answer (score 1):

No, Selenium does not (neccessarily) convert Java to JavaScript or the like.

Citing http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp:

> Selenium-WebDriver makes direct calls to the browser using each
>   browser’s native support for automation. How these direct calls are
>   made, and the features they support depends on the browser you are
>   using.

The Selenium WebDriver has a browser-specific part which is usually embedded in the browser as a module, extension, or plugin which offers an interface to the Selenium script running e.g., in your Java JUnit code.

How this plug-in interacts with the browser depends on its implementation. I would guess in most cases, first compiling to javascript and then executing javascript in the browser is too inefficient. Where possible, I guess that the developers would directly use/call internal API in the webbrowser to access the (internal) DOM and interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) Selenium docs:

> Selenium-WebDriver makes direct calls to the browser using each
>   browser’s native support for automation. How these direct calls are
>   made, and the features they support depends on the browser you are
>   using.

A really comprehensive description of Webdriver's interanals you can find under this 
[link](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html). Some of nice figures from there:

Layers of Selenium Javascript Library:

[image: Figure 16.3: Layers of Selenium Javascript Library]

Overview of the Firefox Driver Architecture:

[image: Overview of the Firefox Driver Architecture]

Answer (score 0):

Simon Stewart, the guiding force behind WebDriver, wrote a [chapter on its design and architecture](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html) for [The Architecture of Open Source Applications](http://www.aosabook.org/en/index.html).  It goes into great detail on how and why things are done.